# Partial data returned from database query in classic asp

Tags: sql, database, asp-classic, db2

**Has anyone ever encountered a problem where a SQL query from a classic ASP page returns *partial* results, but no errors?**

I have a situation where a particular query on a page (one of many throughout the system) is returning a **different** number of rows each time it is run, and always **less** than the "correct" number, as determined by running the SQL against the server directly.

I think this may be related to the connection timeout (since this occurs with a long-running query and my timing shows that it is returning very close to the timeout), but I am receiving no timeout errors. Instead, as far as I can tell, it causes no errors, and returns a valid `DataSet` which the code then loops over to build the results table.

Since there is no indication that an error has occurred, there is no suggestion that the data is not complete which means that users can no longer trust this report. Generally with this system, where SQL timeouts do occur frequently for "large" queries, we get error messages displayed on the page.

**Investigations**

- I've check the HTML source to make sure there are no injected error's that I'm missing and that all tags are well-formed and that expected page elements are present. This indicates it's not an error writing a particular row from the results.
  ** Furthermore, the number of rows returned is **different** each time.
- I've verified that the exact same query is being run each time.
- I've verified that the data in the DB is not changin underneath the report (it's historic and I've cross-checked by running the report and the query against the DB at the same time.)
- I've tried to manually print any errors from the [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/635717/15667), but get nothing.
- I've tried changing the timeout (though this hasn't helped as I can only do
  this on the Dev environment and there there is not sufficient data in
  the DB to reach the timeout, due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095487/classic-asp-application-experiencing-sql-server-timeouts-and-sql-server-does) issue.).
- There are only around 20 rows in total expected, so not an issue with a very large dataset.

**Has anyone run into a situation where a SQL query from a classic asp page only returns partial results, and is there any way to check for or prevent this condition?**

**Setup**:

- Classic asp web application
- Heavy use throughout of `ADODB.Connection` objects for connecting to the DB2 server backend databases.
- The database is **static** as far as the queried data is concerned.

Shared connection initilization as follows:

```
connString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;User ID=xxx;Data Source=XXX;Extended Properties=""DSN=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX;"""
Set conn = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
conn.Mode = adOpenReadOnly
conn.Open connString
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600
```

Usage as follows:

```
query = " SELECT blah FROM Foo WHERE ... " ' big long list of clauses defined from user selections.
cmd.CommandText = sql
Set oRs = cmd.Execute

Resposne.Write "<table>..." ' Write table headers here'
Do while (Not oRs.eof)
     Response.Write "<tr>...</tr>" ' WRite details from oRs here
     oRs.MoveNext
Loop
Response.Write "</table>"
```

Comment: How are you validating if there are errors?  With classic ASP, error messages tend to get injected into the HTML and can be hidden from view if they are embedded in certain tags.  Are you checking the source HTML of the page when you check for errors?

Comment: @mellamokb Yes exactly, the source for the page looks clean and well formed, ie: no errors visible and all expected page elements are present.

Comment: Even including the `</table>` closing table tag?

Comment: by the way, the last line should be `response.write "</table>"` (typo)

Comment: Do you have any script timeout for ASP itself?  I think the default there might be 60 or 90 seconds.

Comment: @mellamokb Yes, even the closing `</table>` tag. I've checked this particularly since usually in this kind of situation there would have been an error writing a row and so the table would be incomplete. I've done this in the raw "view source" in various browsers since Chrome etc. usually automatically complete such unclosed elements in their inspectors.

Comment: @mellamokb There is a script timeout, I believe it's set to 30 minutes.

Comment: @Rodolfo Thanks, fixed. As I'm sure you can tell, this is not the "actual" code, just an illustration of the structure, though the real code is not much more complex.

Comment: one thing you can try to test is dividing the query in different parts to rule out if it's a thing of amount of rows returned, or maybe some particularity of the data

Comment: @Rodolfo Good suggestion thanks, but in the particular case, there are only 22 rows which should be returned (the "big/large" I was referring to is the size of the table in the database, not the result set).

Comment: @xan oh, I was assuming it was a long list of rows. So that is odd indeed.  So the query takes a long time but returns only 22 rows as a result hmm...  Maybe try using a disconnected recordset to see what happens?

Comment: @Rodolfo Yes, it's really strange because this system / same setup routinely handles queries over similar / larger data volumes and often  renders very large results sets. What it *feels* like, is where you manually cancel a long-running query against the database and it returns you the results set as far as it had got to anyway...

Comment: @xan maybe add an `order by` to the query, that way it should send all rows at once and you can rule in or out timeout issues

Comment: @Rodolfo That is an excellent suggestion, I'll give it a go and update the question with my results...

Comment: @Rodolfo Adding the OrderBy seems to have the desired result, though I'm still none the wiser as to what is causing this in the first place! Do you want to put that as an answer to the question?

Comment: @xan oh well was more a suggestion of how to identify the problem, but if it solved your issue, sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `order by` to the query, that way it should send all rows at once and you can rule in or out timeout issues

Comment: Accepting this answer as it gave me a workaround which I hadn't thought of.