# Classic ASP unknown error occurred

Tags: asp-classic

I have written the following code:

```
strConnection ="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=PC-101\SQLEXPRESSR2;Database=LDS;Integrated Security=true"

Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

select_SQL = "select * from tblMonthlySales order by store_id"

On Error Resume Next

rs.open(strConnection , select_SQL)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   response.Write(Err)
On Error Goto 0 ' But don't let other errors hide!
' Code to cope with the error here
End If
On Error Goto 0 ' Reset error handling.
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 for my database.

And I am not able to catch the error and getting this message

> *An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
>   If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.*

Is my connecting string wrong?

I had also tried this connection string:

```
strConnection ="Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=PC-101\SQLEXPRESSR2;Database=LDS;Integrated Security=SSPI;DataTypeCompatibility=80;"
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It is probably your use of Integrated Security. The user trying to access the database is the account your ASP is running under - not the account that is calling it. You might get a better idea of the error by turning friendly error messages off in your browser.

Comment: @JamesCulshaw How can i turn it off.

Comment: @JamesCulshaw You are correct Connection string is buggy

Comment: From an IE side you needs to go to Tools->Internet Options->Advanced and then uncheck show friendly error messages. As @Caner G notes below if you are using IIS7 and above you will need to cnahe some settings in IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please enable your configuration to get error details?
This might work to do that : [asp errors not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524625/asp-errors-not-displayed)